# Возможные причины неуправляемых крашей сетевого приложения

Tags: c++, многопоточность, сервер, tcp

Есть система видеонаблюдения, состоящая из клиентов (C++) транслирующих видео-кадры на сервер, веб-клиентов, просматривающих кадры с сервера (JS/WebSocket), и, собственно, самого сервера на C++. Сервер периодически "падает", выводя сначала окошко с заголовком "Visual C++ runtime error" и кнопкой "OK", по нажатию которой появляется стандартное окно аварийного завершения программы Windows. Периодичность крашей не понятная - может "лечь" через минуту после запуска при нагрузке в 3-10 подключений, а может "лечь" дня через три при нагрузке 50-70 постоянных соединений в течение рабочего дня.

Опишу немного общую логику сервера.

После привязки сервера к адресу запускается бесконечный цикл прослушивания такого вида:

```
while(true){
    if (accept_socket = accept(server_socket, NULL, NULL)){
        CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)ConnectionHandler, (LPVOID)accept_socket, 0, NULL);}
    Sleep(1);
}
```

То есть для каждого подключения создаётся поток, функция которого выглядит так:

```
void ConnectionHandler(SOCKET client_socket){
    std::string data;
    int error = 0;
    while(!error){
        error = RecvAll(client_socket, data); // должно быть нуль если всё ОК, принимает адреса SOCKET& и std::string&
        if (error || !data.size()){break;}
        // тут идёт switch/case типов динных по первым байтам data
        // результат обработки либо записывается в глобальную переменную
        // либо возвращается по клиентскому сокету в ответ
    }
    closesocket(client_socket);
}
```

У меня подозрения либо на сетевую часть, либо на одновременное чтение/запись одной переменной из разных потоков. Под одной переменной я понимаю например `std::map<std::string, Client> Clients`, где первый параметр в паре ID, а второй структура `Client`, которая содержит имя клиента, буфер с jpeg-ом камеры, буфер с jpeg-ом экрана и время последней активности. Когда на сервер приходит кадр от клиента, он попадает в один из этих буферов структуры Client по идентификатору клиента, и в это же время сервер может отправлять этот буфер смотрящему веб-клиенту.

В общем всё работает, камеры/экраны всем кому надо видно, недосылов данных нет, утечек памяти нет... Но в непредвиденный момент краш без объяснений и видимых причин.

Может логика вам покажется странной для данного типа задач, или сетевая реализация не правильной, или потоков столько быть не должно... Пожалуйста выскажете ваше мнение по данному вопросу - код неуправляемый, не знаю где искать неисправность, а сервер нужен стабильный.

**UPDATE!**

Проблема решена благодаря синхронизация потоков при помощи функций WinAPI `CreateMutex`, `WaitForSingleObject`, `ReleaseMutex`.

Всем спасибо за разъяснения.

Comment: Операции с `map` проходят под мьютексом (lock/unlock)?

Comment: @avp, нет, но писать в конкретный элемент `map` по ID может только единственный владелец данного ID, читать могут многие.

Comment: В момент записи внутренняя структура map может быть в несогласованном состоянии. Поэтому читатель может обратиться при поиске по не корректому адресу и все рухнет.

Comment: На фоне вопросов про "функция, проверяющая, что число больше А и меньше Б" ваш вопрос меня очень радует своей сложностью. )) Хотя отвечать на него может быть тоже непросто — вашего приложения у людей нет, ошибку не воспроизвести. Имхо, можно спросить "какими методами и инструментами дебажить такие ошибки".

Comment: Ошибку в таких делах искать сложно, а бывает, что очень долго найти ничего не удаётся. Но как минимум одну ошибку уже нашли — avp Вам правильно указал. Вы, видимо, не совсем понимаете межпоточное взаимодействие. Много потоков могут _читать_ одну и ту же разделяемую переменную без проблема, но если появляется хоть один поток, который _модифицирует_ оную, то она должна быть защищена. В противном случае имеют место «гонки» и неопределённое поведение, которое, в том числе, может выражаться в падении программы.

Comment: @ixSci, а защищать нужно перед записью, или также при каждом чтении? Просто не представляю что будет, если переменную будут читать, когда её захочет записать "владелец", залочив её. Также хочу уточнить: ставить lock ведь достаточно на конкретной паре map, весь map не нужно "тормозить"?

Comment: Нужно защищать **весь** `map` при **любом** его использовании: чтение/запись — не важно. Если «чтецов» много, а «писателей» мало (т.е. читают часто, а пишут редко) тогда можно попробовать использовать shared lock (он же read-write lock), тогда «чтецы» не будут блокироваться, пока «писатель» не «придёт».

Comment: @ixSci, Дело в том, что "писатель", когда транслирует камеру, пишет в свой `Agents[ID].Camera = data.substr(break_index + 1);` 24 раза в секунду, и ему должно быть пофиг читают его или нет - его дело отдавать кадры. А если таких "писателей" штук 20 одновременно, как же тогда лочить весь map... это какие тормоза тогда будут при просмотре?? Как же быть в этой ситуации?

Comment: С точки зрения `map`, всё, что Вы описали является операцией чтения и не требует блокировки. Но если во время такого чтения происходит вставка нового элемента, или же удаление старого, в таком случае блокировка необходима всего `map`. Если же несколько потоков пытаются писать в один элемент `map` (Agents[ID].Camera, например), тогда блокировать нужно только этот элемент.

Comment: А у вас нет возможности получить minidump и посмотреть в какой строе кода падает? Сделайте unittest который эмулируюет большую нагрузку 1000 подключений например. По описанию проблемы у вас явно многопоточная гонка.

Comment: @ixSci, спасибо за разъяснения. Проинспектирую код и забью мьютексами где нужно. Отпишусь по результатам.

Comment: Не нужно ничего подозревать, обкладываете трейсами наиболее подзрительные места, и гоняйте сервак на рабочей нагрузке. Потом курите полученные логи в поисках места и причины падения. Если не получается, то меняйте область поиска, нагрузку поменяйте, и снова курите. Еще иногда полезно системные журналы покурить.

Comment: @ixSci, а нужно ли блокировать map, если я просто проверяю наличие в нём определённого ключа таким образом: `if (Queries.count(ID)){...` или использую итератор для обхода элементов без их модификации?

Comment: Если где-то в это время может происходит модификация `map` — да, нужно блокировать при любом чтении структуры `map`, а обход `map`а и подсчёт количества являются чтением структуры. Вообще, я рекомендую Вам почитать литературу по многопоточному программированию, потому что это довольно сложная тема, чтобы влезать в неё неподготовленным.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хотя в целом на вопрос уже ответили, на всякий случай поясню проблему с блокировкой map.

Принципиально для него есть 4 операции: добавление узла, поиск уза, чтение содержимого узла и запись содержимого в узел (узел - это пара ключ-значение).
В std::map для всех этих операций можно использовать синтаксис clientMap["key"], но это очень плохая идея для многопоточной программы.

Так как у вас узлы добавляются только один раз, после чего не меняются, я бы рекомендовал реализовать безопасные функции для добавления и поиска элементов, которые возвращают ссылки на узлы, а содержимое узлов читать уже можно без блокировки. При этом std::map гарантирует, что при вставке элементов никакие ссылки не станут недействительными, т.е. если вы уже получили ссылку (итератор) на пару значений, а после этого произошла вставка нового элемента, предыдущая ссылка всё еще будет действительна. Для многопоточных программ стандарт мало что гарантирует (зависит от версии), но мне сложно представить реализацию итератора, которая гарантирует валидность при вставке в однопоточной программе, но не гарантирует в многопоточной.

Вот пример для иллюстрации:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

template<class K, class V>
typename std::map<K,V>::iterator safeInsert(std::mutex& mutex, std::map<K,V>& map, const std::pair<K,V>& kv){
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock{mutex};
    auto ret = map.insert(kv);
    return ret.first;
}

template<class K, class V>
typename std::map<K,V>::iterator safeFind(std::mutex& mutex, std::map<K,V>& map, const K& key){
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock{mutex};
    return map.find(key);
}

int main()
{
  std::map<std::string, int> map;
  std::mutex mutex;
  safeInsert(mutex, map, {"123", 0});
  auto iter123 = safeFind(mutex, map, std::string("123"));
  safeInsert(mutex, map, {"321", 1});
  std::cout << iter123->second <<std::endl; // 0, после вставки итератор всё еще валиден
  std::cout << safeFind(mutex, map, std::string("321"))->second <<std::endl; // 1
}
```

При этом не осуществляется проверка на наличие элемента в map. Если она нужна, её нужно делать под той же блокировкой, иначе сравнивать с map.end() будет небезопасно. Например, можно передавать дополнительным аргументов ссылку на bool, куда можно записывать соответствующий признак.

Если же возможна запись в уже добавленный узел, придется вешать блокировку ещё и на сам объект-значение, тут ничего не поделаешь.

Comment: Был удивлён, когда попытался создать `std::mutex` - MinGW про него ничего не знает, хотя и сам предлагает <mutex> при написамии "#include <mu". Вот колдую над WinAPI-шными CreateMutex, ReleaseMutex...

Comment: @Iceman, у Вас либо старый minGW, либо что-то делаете не так.

Comment: @Iceman, у вас mingw32? Он действительно отстаёт в плане новых  стандартов, но C++11 там вроде бы есть. Вы добавили флаг `-std=c++11` ?

Comment: @ВикторСмирнов, да mingw32, флаг конечно же установлен. Просто NetBeans подчёркивает красным строки с `std::mutex` и не предлагает его в автозаполнении. Компилить не пытался. Использовал `EnterCriticalSection` и `LeaveCriticalSection` из WinAPI. Оно ведь так же работает?

Comment: @Iceman, да, критические секции аналогичны std::mutex, только что нужно следить, чтобы не бросались исключения между EnterCriticalSection и LeaveCriticalSection. Можно обернуть захват секции в простенький класс, который в конструкторе захватывает секцию, в деструкторе освобождает  (аналог std::lock_guard)

Comment: @ВикторСмирнов, во время тестов крашей не было, выкатил обновление с синхронизацией потоков - посмотрю до конца недели на результат, потом приму ответ. Спасибо за разъяснения и рекомендации по `map`

Comment: @ВикторСмирнов, обновил вопрос. С клиентами проблема крашей решелись, сервер всё ещё глючит...

Comment: @Iceman, я плохо помню winapi, но рекомендовал бы продумать следующие моменты: что происходит, если два клиента подключаются одновременно, и сколько всего клиентов могут подключиться,  т.к. максимальное количество потоков ограничено. Если не ошибаюсь, их дескрипторы ещё и закрывать нужно вручную после завершения, или ставить специальные флаги. Вообще, стоит добавить обработку ошибок для всех функций winapi, в том числе accept и CreateTread, если этого не сделано. И Sleep меня смущает, он выглядит лишним, это же синхронный api

Comment: Хотя претензия к sleep, скорее всего неверна, я точно не помню, как работает accept. Скорее всего нужно использовать механизм для подключения группы клиентов - асинхронные интерфейсы или списки подключений, если не ошибаюсь, это acceptList, или что-то вроде того.